# Issues with multiple elseif statements

Tags: php, if-statement

Trying to create a lengthy series of if else statements. Basically, four different scenarios to bring up different button based on queries.

If the event is free, have a button saying so.

However, if the event is free, but you have to RSVP (like our meetups), show this button

Or if there are tickets but the event isn’t free but has a discount, show this button,

Else if there are tickets but they aren’t free, show this button.

And this is what I currently have.

```
if ( isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) == 'Free' ) {
    echo '<button class="btn-free">This Event is Free!</button></a>';
} elseif( isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]) && (isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ])) == 'Free' ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-rsvp">Free with RSVP</button></a>';
} elseif( isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]) && (isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ])) != 'Free' && (isset($additional_fields[ 'Discounts' ]))) {
    echo '<a href="' . $additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-discount">Tickets ' . $additional_fields[ 'Discount Text' ] . '</button></a>';
} elseif( isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]) ){
    echo '<a href="' . $additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-tkts">Get Tickets</button></a>';
}
```

Code works.... to a point. If I have an event that is free, I get the This Event is Free button, but if I have an event that is free but also offers tickets / rsvp, I still get the first free button with no link. The second step should be occurring here. Not the first. Same deal if add a price or anything beyond the word 'Free'.

Is my order correct? Or something else in the code?

Comment: `isset()` returns true/false

Comment: The reason that's happening is because if the event is FREE, the if statement ends and doesn't continue with the rest of the `elseif` cases.

Comment: `isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) && $additional_fields[ 'Price' ] == 'Free'` same with the rest of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have problems with the order of the conditionals and the use of `isset()`. I think the following code is what you are aiming for:

```
if( isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]) && isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) && $additional_fields[ 'Price' ] == 'Free' ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-rsvp">Free with RSVP</button></a>';
} elseif ( isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ])  && $additional_fields[ 'Price' ] == 'Free' ) {
    echo '<button class="btn-free">This Event is Free!</button></a>';
} elseif( isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]) && isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) && isset($additional_fields[ 'Discounts' ])) {
    echo '<a href="' . $additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-discount">Tickets ' . $additional_fields[ 'Discount Text' ] . '</button></a>';
} elseif( isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]) ){
    echo '<a href="' . $additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-tkts">Get Tickets</button></a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something regarding the order.

Answer (score 1):

You should try testing if the key is set separatelly from whether or not it equals to 'Free' for an example.

```
if ( isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) && $additional_fields[ 'Price' ] == 'Free' ){
do this
}
```

Since isset will only return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will get the first statement because in your first statement you have checked that

```
if ( isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) == 'Free' )
```

So now in the first statement **Price is free** so when the `if()` is satisfied so why code will go to the else statment

**And also u used `isset()` Its return you just boolean**
Use this

```
if ( $additional_fields[ 'Price' ] == 'Free' && !isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ])) {
echo "Your button"
```

} ...

use this for all statments

And let me know if still there is any issue.

Hope it helps you

Comment: But if I don't use isset, I'll get PHP errors. That typically is what happens.

Comment: You can also use isset with and condition like this

if ( isset($additional_fields[ 'Price' ]) && $additional_fields[ 'Price' ] == 'Free' && !isset($additional_fields[ 'Tickets' ]))

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking and setting your variables in advance to make the code easier to read.

```
$tickets = (isset($additional_fields['Tickets'])) ? $additional_fields['Tickets'] : false;
$price = (isset($additional_fields['Price'])) ? $additional_fields['Price'] : false;
$discounts = (isset($additional_fields['Discounts'])) ? $additional_fields['Discounts'] : false;
$discount_text = (isset($additional_fields['Discount Text'])) ? $additional_fields['Discount Text'] : false;
```

Since all of your conditions rely on `tickets` being set, just check in the beginning and get it out of the way.

```
if ($tickets) {
    if ($price == "Free") {
        echo '<a href="' . $tickets . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-rsvp">Free with RSVP</button></a>';
    } else if ($discounts) {
        echo '<a href="' . $tickets . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-discount">Tickets ' . $discount_text . '</button></a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . $tickets . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn-tkts">Get Tickets</button></a>';
    }
}
```